# Antd table: How to remove the divider line between table column heading

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro, ant-design-vue

As you can see in the image there is line which divides each table column heading. I wish to remove these dividing lines from this table. I'm using Antd table component.
https://ant.design/components/table#examples

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using css:

```
.ant-table-thead > tr > th {
    border-right: none !important;
  }
```

solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use css:

> .ant-table-thead > tr > th {   position: static !important }

Comment: Can you add Language details i.e you want your answer for HTML, React, etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).